# ¿Cómo puedo eliminar un fichero en Python con su ruta guardada dentro de una variable?

Tags: python

```
eliminado = input("Introduce el nombre del registro a eliminar: ")
ruta_archivo = os.path.abspath(eliminado)
os.remove(ruta_archivo)
```

Comment: como tal debe funcionar, lo que si, cuando pases el camino hay que usar esta "/" y no "\", otra cosa, te puede dar problemas sino ejecutas el script como administrador.

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza `raw_input` en lugar de `input`

```
eliminado = raw_input("Introduce el nombre del registro a eliminar: ")
```

Este fue el resultado de mi prueba:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: `raw_input` es una instrucción de Python 2, obsoleto y sin soporte. A menos que el solicitante especifique lo contrario, se debe asumir que se trata de la versión vigente, Python 3.x